# In sympy, is there a way to suppress the writing of function arguments, such as writing f instead of f(x)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I am doing calculus with a lot of functions of one variable in a Jupyter Notebook.

I am displaying the results using latex with

```
from sympy import *
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex 
init_printing()
```

When I print something like `Function('f')('x')`, it comes out as `f(x)`. I want it to come out as `f`. Is this possible?

Comment: If you have an expression that contains `f(x)`, then every time you print `expr`, you can do the following instead: `expr.subs(f(x), symbol('f'))`. This will be your desired output. Edit: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695886/sympy-print-only-function-name).

Comment: @Maelstrom thanks for this. The question you linked didn't seem to help much because it apparently broke some functionality (at least using it naively). But defining my own `def display_(expr)` function to automatically make all my substitutions worked out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for a solution, you can use the following function for any number of function inputs:

```
def display_no_args(expr):
    functions = expr.atoms(Function)
    reps = {}

    for fun in functions:
        reps[fun] = Symbol(fun.name)

    display(expr.subs(reps))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for trig functions. Passing an equation with a cosine gives me `AttributeError: 'cos' object has no attribute 'name'`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to make a class producing function.

```
import sympy as sp

def my_Function(name):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **options):
        cls.short_latex = True
        function = sp.Function.__new__(cls, *args, **options)
        return function

    def _latex(cls, printer):
        _func = printer._print(cls.func)
        _args = printer._print(cls.args)
        if cls.short_latex:
            return r'%s' % (_func)
        else:
            return r'%s%s' % (_func, _args)

    return type(name, (sp.Function,),{'__new__':__new__,'_latex': _latex})

x = sp.symarray('x',3)
f = sp.Matrix([ my_Function(f'f_{i}')(*x) for i in range(3)])
f
```